# Meaning: How terrible you are here

Tags: meaning

In *The Simpsons Movie*, Flanders says this to Bart when Bart comes into the church.

> How good to see you. And **how terrible you're here.**

I am not familiar with this usage of *how* here; as unfamiliar as I am, I couldn't not think it meant Flanders felt terrible that Bart was there. I assume, as Bart is not a church-going boy, that it actually means Flanders could see how terrible the things are going; "it must be terrible that you've come here." Could you tell me how it's used and give some examples? And is this common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't imagine anybody saying this in real life, except to be deliberately offensive (possibly as a joke between friends). The only meaning I can get from it is "it is a terrible thing that you are here". It's an alteration of "How wonderful that you're here".